# using redirection from servlet

Tags: java, servlets

i am using a servlet to bring in a login page for my web application.but once i login and click on "submit" button,i should be redirected to another page. how do i do this? i am currently trying to use

```
RequestDispatcher rd = null;
rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/NextServlet");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Also tried using

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/myProject/NextServlet");
```

but nothing happens on click of submit, I do not want to include a link with href and use. What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to see a java server page or the content of a servlet? If you want to access to this `NextServlet`, at least make sure this servlet prints any HTML code or forward/redirects to a JSP.

Comment: i have updated the answer.. please check

Comment: have you mentioned this path in your web.xml?

Comment: yes i have included a simple hhtml code in my NextServlet  and  i have in mentioned the following in my web.xml  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>RequestParamExample</servlet-name>  
     <servlet-class>com.xyz.RequestParamExample</servlet-class>      
  </servlet>
   
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>RequestParamExample</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: RequestParamExample is the servlet where i have included dispatcher as said in the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
response.sendRedirect("NextServlet");
```

Comment: path itself contains context path, i have only given an alternative to request dispatcher

Comment: Not necessarily, and you even need to use `Response#encodeRedirectURL` as shown here: [Servlet: URL redirect](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/ServletURLredirect.htm).

Comment: it is required when you need to encode your url, otherwise you can directly send to that url

Comment: let us taken an example of any url... response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com"); ... try it

Comment: Ok, what about `path = "somePage.jsp";`?

Comment: let us assume your application path... which is context path is http://localhost:8080/myApp then we can have response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/myApp/somePage.jsp");...

Comment: That's the problem, you're *assuming* something that's not necessarily true, and here we don't *assume* things to give accurate answers. If you will *assume* anything, it should be clearly specified in the answer. Also, what if you have 100 or more JSPs, will you have like 100 constants like `String PAGE1 = "http://localhost:8080/myApp/page1.jsp";` and on? What if you change port app ot the site is not localhost anymore or you have subdirectories?

Comment: or if you are in the same context... you can simply write response.sendRedirect("somePage.jsp");

Comment: we are not here to write the code for others.... we only give hints and solve issues

Comment: have you ever used response.sendRedirect(""); ?

Comment: If you think like that, you're in the wrong place. Before keep answering other questions, you should read [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/182862). And yes, I've used as shown in the link in my comment, and it never gave problems.

Comment: exactly! everything other than my html page gets called.i have tried it with www.gmail.com,google,w3schools etc...but when i call a html page inside my project it doesn't work.it stays in the same login page:(

Comment: What is the location of your html pages? is it parallel to web-inf?

Comment: i have placed it under WEb-INF/classes

Comment: here is the problem.. put them parallel to web-inf... where you have placed your jsps.. it will definitely work

Comment: main_app/web-inf  and main_app/htmlpages

Comment: can you please elaborate on "put them parallel to web-inf"

Comment: see my last comment... suppose your app name is myApp which is the parent folder of the app the Web-INF location is **myApp/Web-INF**, similarly put all the html files like **myApp/<here your all html>**  e.g. myApp/index.html

Comment: have a look at this link http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/directory-structure.shtml

Comment: no,will check out again and get back to you...thank you so much for the replies

Comment: it will definitely work....now what is actual issue? What do you want to do and how are doing it?

Comment: the basic thing is i am converting a project that uses hibernate into a web project.as the first step, i have called a servlet from my web.xml for login and i am able to get the form once i run on my server.but after validating the form,i.e., on clicking "submit" button, i should be redirected to my next html page wherein other details of the project are given. this is my issue and what i am supposed to do. can you help me on the basis of this, leaving the previous posts aside, may be i have made a mistake in my approach itself??!

Comment: so you want to redirect to the detailed html page only if the validation is done...?

Comment: yes, i have the username and pwd accessed from the database through hibernate connectivity and check against the entered username and pwd.if a matching occurs, redirection should occur, else remain with an error message

Comment: had you changed your html file locations i.e. paralled to web-inf?

Comment: the path is like myApp/WebContent/WEB-INF/WelcomePage.html and similarly myApp/WebContent/WEB-INF/WelcomePage.jsp If I try to change the path of .html file, i get an error in the jsp file.My jsp file is as below <%@ page info="Welcome iPTS" %>
<html>
<head><title>myApp</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<%@ include file="WelcomePage.html" %>
<table>
<tr>
<td width=150> &nbsp; </td>
<td width=250 align=right> <h1>Welcome to myApp!</h1> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html> and html file is also very simple with only one statement to be printed

Comment: had u seen the link - http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/directory-structure.shtml

Comment: aawww no! when i try to run my jsp on server,it gives the following error..HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.32.......i never got an idea to check it!there lies the problem i believe.thank you so much.

Comment: i was telling you... your welcome :).. Please mark it as answer if you find your solution

Comment: hi..now when i run my jsp or an html file,the entire application is running,i.e., the servlet that i have called in web.xml is being called even when i run the individual file!

Comment: i am not getting you... please elaborate

Comment: i am trying to test if my jsp file is working, previously i had placed it under WEB-INF folder and so was getting the error as previously said. now, with your reference, i have taken it out of WEB-INF and placed under WebContent i.e, in parallel. Now when i try to run my jsp file,the login page that my initial servlet contains is visible and not the contents of my jsp file...i have posted another question,please check

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `contextPath` in your redirect URL as :

```
  String destinationURL = request.getContextPath()+"/NextServlet";
  RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destinationURL);
  rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: @blackhole When you say "not working", what is  happening? Are you getting some message/error? Also did you make sure, its reaching up to this code as I suspect the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: i am not redirected to the page, instead it stays in the same page,but the username and password fields reset. i dont have any errors also.i tried increasing my log4j error logging, but not able to trace

Comment: I suspect, its not reaching up to there. Can you share little more of your code?

Comment: i am now getting an error as below: Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-4" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:219)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:228)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:228)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:228)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:228)

Comment: @blackhole Can you look litte down in the stack trace and see which line of your code(it will have name of one of your classes) is cause this over flow error?

Comment: yes its is in the requestdispatcher.forward(request,response)...my code is as below:  String destinationURL = request.getContextPath()+ "myServletPath";
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(destinationURL);
 rd.forward(request, response); <---error here and these lines of code are in my doPost() of my first servlet that i have called in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the "action" of your form in html?

```
<form action="your_jsp_script.jsp" method="post">
```

Comment: yes @sifeng, i have mentioned the action,but i have linked it to call a html page and not a jsp page!am i wrong there?

Comment: the script in "<form action=...>" will be executed when you click the submit button. If it is just a html page, nothing will happen.

Comment: hi,once i have changed to <form action="WelcomePage.jsp" method=POST>, i am redirected to some page but, its empty and only the out.prinltn() statements are visible...my jsp file is as below : <%@ page info="request param example" %>
<html>
<head><title>iPTS</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" background="background.gif">
<%@ include file="WelcomePage.html" %>
<table>
<tr>
<td width=150> &nbsp; </td>
<td width=250 align=right> <h1>Welcome to iPTS!</h1> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>  again,where am i wrong?